# Как генерировать картинку на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html, изображения

Как генерировать картинку на сайте с заранее заданным фоном и текстом полученным из input? Нужно чтобы текст этот накладывался на картинку заранее подготовленную и получалась картинка с этим текстом. И это делалось автоматически бы на сайте

Comment: Canvas (в баузере) или GD (на сервере)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так)) это так примерно..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var myImage = new Image(100, 200);
  myImage.src = 'http://www.fullhdoboi.com/wallpapers/thumbs/6/kartinka-apelsiny-1885.jpg';

  var ctx = $('#cnv').get(0).getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);


  $('#qwe').keyup(function() {
    ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillText($(this).val(), 50, 50);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<body>

  <canvas id="cnv" width=500 height=500></canvas>
  <input type="text" name="asd" id="qwe" />

</body>
```